# Javascript: How to detect when a style change happens on the page?

Tags: javascript, dom, styles, mutation-observers

I want to detect when a `style` change happens on any DOM element on a page (i.e. changes to any element's position, height, width, visibility, etc). [While not related to the question directly, this is for a chrome extension I am working on]

I am using the Mutation Observer API. However, it seems to only be able to detect changes to the serialized markup, but not direct DOM properties.  That is, it can detect changes to the `style` *attribute* of an element but not to its actual `style` *property* (since, based on the CSS applied, the actual `style` may change due to changes in any attribute etc).

So, I am having to observe changes to *all* attributes for the *entire* subtree of the `document` element. This seems to be causing a performance hit, since some sites, like FB, generate a lot of mutation events if I do that, while I am interested in only a small subset.

Is there a better way to track only `style` related changes?

Comment: Check if this will fancy you http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/ , but capturing events on style changes is not doable.